# Spring-Cloud-Stream-Kafka Custom Health check not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am using spring-cloud-stream-kafka in my spring-boot(consumer) application.The health of the app is inaccurate, 'UP' even when the app can't connect to Kafka(Kafka broker is down). I have read articles on kafka health check. It looks like kafka health check is disabled in spring actuator health check.

So, I managed to write the following code to enable kafka health check for my app. I think, I am missing some connection between the app config and my code and I don't see the Kafka health working.

(1) I am creating a custom health indicator bean as follows:

```
      import java.util.HashMap;
      import java.util.Map;

      import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
      import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer;
      import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass;
      import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaBinderHealthIndicator;
      import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder;
      import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.properties.KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties;
      import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
      import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
      import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
      import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
      import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;

      @Configuration
      @ConditionalOnClass(name = "org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator")
      public class KafkaBinderHealthIndicatorConfiguration {

        @Bean
        KafkaBinderHealthIndicator healthIndicator(KafkaMessageChannelBinder kafkaMessageChannelBinder,
            KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties configurationProperties) {
          Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
          Map<String, Object> mergedConfig = configurationProperties.getConsumerConfiguration();
          if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(mergedConfig)) {
            props.putAll(mergedConfig);
          }
          if (!props.containsKey(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG)) {
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, configurationProperties.getKafkaConnectionString());
          }
          ConsumerFactory<?, ?> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
          KafkaBinderHealthIndicator indicator = new KafkaBinderHealthIndicator(kafkaMessageChannelBinder, consumerFactory);
          indicator.setTimeout(configurationProperties.getHealthTimeout());
          return indicator;
        }
      }
```

(2) Created binder config:

```
          import java.io.IOException;

          import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
          import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
          import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration;
          import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration;
          import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties;
          import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
          import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.Binder;
          import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder;
          import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.admin.Kafka10AdminUtilsOperation;
          import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.properties.KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties;
          import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.properties.KafkaExtendedBindingProperties;
          import org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner;
          import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
          import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
          import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
          import org.springframework.kafka.security.jaas.KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer;

          @Configuration
          @ConditionalOnMissingBean(Binder.class)
          @Import({ KafkaAutoConfiguration.class, PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class,
              KafkaBinderHealthIndicatorConfiguration.class })
          @EnableConfigurationProperties({ KafkaExtendedBindingProperties.class })
          public class KafkaBinderConfiguration {

            @Autowired
            private KafkaExtendedBindingProperties kafkaExtendedBindingProperties;

          //  @Autowired
          //  private ProducerListener               producerListener;

            @Bean
            KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties configurationProperties(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
              return new KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties();
            }

            @Bean
            KafkaTopicProvisioner provisioningProvider(KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties configurationProperties) {
              return new KafkaTopicProvisioner(configurationProperties, new Kafka10AdminUtilsOperation());
            }

            @Bean
            KafkaMessageChannelBinder kafkaMessageChannelBinder(KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties configurationProperties,
                KafkaTopicProvisioner provisioningProvider) {

              KafkaMessageChannelBinder kafkaMessageChannelBinder = new KafkaMessageChannelBinder(configurationProperties,
                  provisioningProvider);
          //    kafkaMessageChannelBinder.setProducerListener(producerListener);
              kafkaMessageChannelBinder.setExtendedBindingProperties(this.kafkaExtendedBindingProperties);
              return kafkaMessageChannelBinder;
            }

            @Bean
            public KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer jaasInitializer() throws IOException {
              return new KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer();
            }

          }
```

3. App properties I have added:

   management.health.binders.enabled = true,
     management.health.kafka.enabled = true

===========OUTPUT=============
When I launch my app locally and hit the /health endpoint, I see the following for kafka:

```
 "binders": {
     "status": "UNKNOWN",
     "kafka": {
     "status": "UNKNOWN"
     }
  },
```

Comment: What version of spring-cloud-stream are you using? I just tried an app locally on the latest snapshot with kafka binder and hit the `/actuator/health` endpoint and saw that the {"status":"UP"} message comes up. While the broker is down seeing the "DOWN" message as well. By default, if `management.health.binders.enabled` property is missing, then it will match and no need to set that property to true. Can you try a simple app without your custom beans for health indicator configuration and see if that works on the latest versions of spring-cloud-stream?

Comment: when the broker was down, the "DOWN" message appeared only after a significant delay after timing out the request to connect to Kafka in the health indicator check.

Comment: compile(group:org.springframework.cloud, name: 'spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka11', version: '1.3.0.RELEASE').  Okay, I am going to try a small app with the latest version. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using 2.0.0.RELEASE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was resolved by using the latest version of 'spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka'. I was using an older version (version older than 1.3.0.RELEASE) initially and the health check for kafka wasnt working. As @Sobychacko suggested, I used the latest version, 2.0.0 REALEASE and the health check for kafka binders was woking fine :) with no custom health indicator beans.

"binders": {
     "status": "UP",
     "kafka": {
     "status": "UP",
     "healthIndicator": {
        "status": "UP"
     }
    }
   },

This check should also work with version 1.3.0.RELEASE